# global keyboard shortcut to open AckMate on OSX

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

I'd like to bind a global keyboard shortcut to open AckMate within TextMate, even if I don't have TextMate open (open the most recent project in that case). How can I do this on Mac OSX?

Comment: Please explain how you want this to work. What project do you want to search? What do you want to have happen if there is no open project? On my system, TextMate does not reopen projects that were open when I quit it, so what do you want to be the object of the search window? If there is no project (or at least folder) open in TextMate, there's no AckMate option -- it's simply disabled.

Comment: Ok good point. I want to open the most recent project. Or if it's easier, let's just assume TextMate is open to a project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Automator, and select to create a new *Service* that receives *No Input* in *Any application*.

Add a single *Run AppleScript* action and paste the following code:

```
tell application "TextMate" to activate
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "TextMate" to tell menu bar 1 to tell menu bar item "Edit" to tell menu 1 to tell menu item "Find" to tell menu 1 to tell menu item "Search Project With AckMate..." to click
```

Save using any name, and assign a keyboard shortcut in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Services*.